# Interesting examples of systems of linear differential equations with constant coefficients

Tags: differential-equations, teaching

In [this paper](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/Rota.pdf), Gian-Carlo Rota wrote:

> A lot of interesting systems with constant coefficients have been discovered in the last thirty years: in control, in economics, in signal
> processing, even in mathematics. None of these attractive examples is presently included in introductory texts. At present all examples of matrix systems one finds in such texts are either planar
> or else they are artificial.

None of these attractive examples were included in this paper either.

What are some examples of what Rota is talking about?

Rota died in 1999, so "the last thirty years" can be construed accordingly, but more recent examples could be included here as well.

Comment: Simple control systems for quadcopters?  The relation between a lie group and its Lie algebra?

Comment: @RyanBudney : Maybe if you can make that into an answer that would be worthwhile. Believe it or not, some of us don't know about simple control systems for quadcopters.

Comment: The spread of an infectious disease? I can't read Rota's mind, but I'm pretty sure "interesting" didn't mean "interesting from the mathematical point of view" but "interesting from the applications' point of view". I don't see how this is research level mathematics. Differential equations with constant coefficients aren't bleeding-edge.

Comment: The main focus of control theory is the replacement of a nonlinear system model with a linear approximation and subsequent manipulations with this linear model.

Comment: @AVK: I've always thought that was called Linear Control Theory, but maybe there's varying conventions out there.   To Michael, the basic idea is to think of the configuration space of a quadcopter: what the gyros say and the data from the rotors.  Then you write down the ODE that tries to stabilize, i.e. make the quadcopter flat.   Non-linear ODEs are often strongly controlled (conjugate) to their various linearizations, so this is a fairly general result.

Comment: @Ryan Budney Almost no one knows about Nonlinear control theory, so in the linear approximation its existence can be neglected :)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi : But applications may shed light on research.

Comment: @RyanBudney : If you teach differential equations, do you include the sorts of systems of which you write here?

Comment: Just once.  I was teaching a 3rd year ODE course and sketched out the control system for a small quadcopter that I was flying over the students' heads.  In hindsight it would have been more appropriate for 4th year students.   I don't recall if I wrote it up all that well, or if I just sketched it up on the fly.  The problem is these students didn't really have the tools to do calculus on $SO_3$ so I had to keep it kind of vague.  This example would probably be better for a computation/simulation course, where students don't need to know all the underlying mathematics.

Comment: I'll see if I have it written down.  But I bet electrical / mechanical engineers on your campus have done this in their courses, perhaps either EE or continuum mechanics -- as a good model should take into account the inertia tensor of the quadcopter.

Comment: @RyanBudney If possible, can you include some lecture slides? I would love to present that as well. Also, any suggestions textbooks on the use of Lie groups/algebras in control theory? There are a bunch of online sources. I was hoping for a math-oriented one with proofs?

Comment: What did Rota mean when calling some matrix systems "planar"?

Comment: A footnote says "Transcribed by Leo Goldmakher. Any errors due to me, not GCR." I has a similar footnote in a transcription I did of a humorous work of fiction, saying I am the transcriber and there is a complicated, subtle, and perplexing question of whom to blame for any transcription errors, and concluded with "Probably Mark Zuckerberg." But I wonder whether it was Rota or someone else who wrote that a certain "argument was pawned off to thousands of unsuspecting classes" instead of "palmed off". Rota was fairly skilled with languages.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I wondered about the word "planar" as well. My guess is that it means a $2\times 2$ matrix.

Comment: I deleted a number of meta comments discussing the merits of this question. Please stay on-topic here, and discuss meta issues on meta.

Answer (score 14):

There is some indication of what Rota had in mind in the book *Ordinary Differential Equations* by Birkhoff and Rota. I don't have a copy handy, but the preview on Amazon has this to say in the Introduction (Chapter 3 is about linear differential equations with constant coefficients):

> Besides reviewing elementary material, Chapter 3 introduces the concepts of transfer function and the Nyquist diagram with their relation to Green's functions. Although widely used in communications engineering for many years, these concepts are ignored in most textbooks on differential equations.

Answer (score 3):

The first example is the harmonic oscillator. Understanding the driven damped harmonic oscillator is the foundation of electrical engineering, at least at RF frequencies.

Control theory has a number of easy systems: a thermostat that varies the energy flowing into a thermal mass that cools according to Newton's law of cooling is one. Then can ask about how particular controllers do given a step shock.

Bottom line is ask your collegues/look at the intro textbooks for those fields. There are a bunch!

Answer (score 2):

There has been some discussion of rigid-body dynamics in the comments. It's a little hard for me to imagine that there was a newly (1967+) "discovered" system of linear differential equations with constant coefficients in such a classical field; however, there was an advance in the field in the 1960s due to Thomas Kane, who found a fresh approach to analyzing rigid-body systems. Kane's method reduces computational labor in many instances, compared to classical approaches.

Rigid-body dynamics tends to be highly nonlinear. But in Kane and Levinson's book, [*Dynamics: Theory and Applications*](https://ecommons.cornell.edu/bitstream/1813/638/10/Dynamics-Theory_opt.pdf), there is a section on linear differential equations. In particular, there is a nontrivial example starting on page 249. Now, I'm sure one could analyze this system without using any of Kane's new ideas, so I don't think it counts as something "discovered in the last thirty years" before 1997. Nevertheless, I think it does count as a serious practical example of a system of linear differential equations with constant coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

"At present all examples of matrix systems one finds in such texts are either planar or else they are artificial." Assuming that "planar" means $2\times2$, thirty years ago I was teaching students about a trio of coupled pendulums. This leads to a $3\times3$ system, and three "eigenstates" (all three swinging together; outside one swinging in opposition with middle one stationary; outside ones swinging together while middle one swings in opposition at twice the amplitude).

I sure didn't invent this example – I must have taken it from some textbook.